# Spyder IDE does not display VispyWidget / Vispy plot

Tags: python, web-crawler, spyder, vispy

I am quite new to python and spyder IDE.

I have a problem with the spyder IDE unable to plot the example from vispy example.

The example I used is gpuimages.py, you can check the source code in the link below:

https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/master/examples/basics/gloo/gpuimage.py

The output from Spyder:

```
VispyWidget(height=800, width=800)
```

But if I manually run the script using command prompt it would run smoothly the plot. Using python command

```
python gpuimages.py
```

I am able to get the output.

So, help me how I able to configure the spyder to run the Vispy example?

Comment: I think you need to add `import vispy` and then `vispy.use('PyQt5')` before `class Canvas` to be able to run that in Spyder. See [here](https://vispy.org/vispy.html#vispy.use) for more details.

Comment: Thank your very much. It's work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation. I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

To make that Vispy example work in Spyder, you need to add

```
import vispy
vispy.use('PyQt5')
```

at the top of your file. That changes the Vispy graphical backend to use `PyQt5`, which is compatible with Spyder, instead of the one Vispy automatically sets.

To learn more about `vispy.use`, please visit this [link](https://vispy.org/vispy.html#vispy.use).